# Typescript - How to import and use RequestInit type from fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, http-headers, fetch-api

I want to create a custom `fetchServer` method in which I can manipulate the different parameters (such as the URL, headers, and so on) in my React application before performing the actual `fetch`.

This method, at the end, uses the common `fetch` from Javascript, which has the following signature:

```
function fetch(input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<Response>
```

So, I've written my `fetchServer` this way:

```
export const fetchServer = async <T>(
  url: string,
  options: any = {},
): Promise<T> => {
  ...
  const alteredOptions = { ...options, /* my custom code */ };
  const rawResponse = await fetch(url, { ...alteredOptions});
  ...
};
```

However, as you can see, I'm using `any` for `options`, because I'm unable to import successfully the `RequestInit` type from anywhere.

I've read [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/207), but it's from `apollo` package (which I'm not using) and it's not solved.

I can try to declare it myself, but then the same happens with `body` and `headers` properties (which have `BodyInit` and `HeadersInit` types).

I've also tried to reference it directly, but ESlint throws an error because it's `undefined` and VSCode seems unable to import it correctly (although it autocompletes it).

```
interface RequestInit
'RequestInit' is not defined : eslint(no-undef)
```

I'm using Typescript v4.6.3, and these are my `tsconfig.json` settings:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
},
```

How should I type my `options` parameter so that it extends the `RequestInit` type parameter of `fetch` method, and I'm able to extend it with my own properties?

Comment: Not sure why that's happening. I can use it directly with typescript v4. You should add your config files in the question as well

Comment: Are you using `@types/web` (or the `dom` lib in your TSConfig compiler options)? The [definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.0.4/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L1610) comes from one of either of those (but don't use both at the same time) — it will be available as an ambient type (globally) and won't need to be imported.

Comment: @UmbQbify and @jsejcksn thank you for your answers. I've editted my question to add my `tsconfig.json` configuration and see if it can help. Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe eslint is at fault here.

Comment: @Unapedra Please read how to create a [mre] and update the question accordingly, including all steps involved — from defining dependencies, running the project, error output, etc. The question should have **everything** needed for someone to be able to reproduce the issue exactly.

Comment: Try using `export const fetchServer = async <T>(req: Request): Promise<T> => {
...
}`, with documentation for `Request` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. Turns out it was not a type error like I thought it was at first. Typescript has the type info from `"DOM"` being included as a lib in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [..., "DOM"],
  }
```

But that error was really only something wrong with eslint and it not seeing `RequestInit` as a global type.

A quick workaround is to add the following to the .ts file that referenced it.

```
/* global RequestInit */
```

You could also add it as a global to your eslintrc file to do the same thing project wide.

```
"globals": {
  "RequestInit": true
}
```